# How to organize C multi-file project?

Tags: c, project

I have three source files and one header file. `main()` in first `.c`, major *(for me it was hard to find a synonym for word "main" ;d)* functions in second `.c`, misc functions -- in last. Libraries including, defines, function prototypes, structs, global variables are in header file.

Is this the right organization?

Which argument should I use to name clang's executable? `-o` works only with one-file projects.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a `makefile`? (And if not: would you like to be?)

Comment: I've heard about `makefile`, but I have no idea why I should use it.

Comment: Why, to simplify your file organization and to properly compile your stuff, of course! The concept was developed to counter such problems as you are having. (And even more.)

Comment: You can write an answer to introduce me to `makefile` ;)

Comment: You wouldn't compile the .h file. if should be something like `clang -O3 main.c functions.c misc.c` and then `clang -o executablefile main.o functions.o misc.o` and to run the program: `./executablefile`. But using a makefile is better. The organisation of your files sounds more or less fine, but your description is not very accurate..

Comment: or maybe cmake (I use it with ninja)  :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky my description as bad as my English language knowledge ;d

Comment: And for a short introduction to make: google "makefile make introduction"

Comment: Worth learning about how a `makefile` is used, but Id note it is not the only way and is not used everywhere (e.g. Microsoft Visual Studio) and is not part of C itself. CMake is maybe the most portable option for dealing with different compilers and IDE's.

Comment: It should be noted that makefiles are mostly a thing of the past before IDE:s existed. Knowing how to write a makefile is not something a beginner (if anyone at all) need to concern themselves about. With a modern IDE, all the .c files added to the project are linked. This is a blessing, as it allows us to forget the dark ages of command line compilation.

Comment: "global variables are in header file" No no no! do yourself a favour and stop using globals. But if you must continue to use them, do not add them to header files (unless they're preceded by `extern` and properly defined in 1 single source file).

Comment: @pmg EVERY function in my project uses this variables. What should I do? Always push their links to functions? Really?

Comment: One easy solution is to group the variables together into a structure ... and yes! pass a pointer to that structure around. For example `struct ProjectVars {int foo; double var; char name[100]; size_t len; /* ... */ };` and `struct ProjectVars data; data.foo = 42; strcpy(data.name, "Project"); data.len = 7;` and `delta = fx1(a, b, c, &data);`

Comment: @pmg but why I shouldn't use the easiest way? Methinks, that programmers always complicate things.

Comment: You might like this article: http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this the right organization?

No, not really.

Basically you want 1 source file to correspond with 1 header file (with the exception of the file that has your `main()` function), so in your example you'd have "second.h" and "last.h".
And don't forget to `#include "second.h"` in "second.c" to have the compiler check everything (and the same for "last.c").

Also, do the `#include` where it's needed. If you use `struct tm` for parameters, for example, `#include <time.h>` in the header and source files. Keep unneeded includes out of header files.

Also remember to properly guard against multiple inclusion with *header guards*

```
#ifndef SECOND_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define SECOND_HEADER_INCLUDED
//avoid #includes
//#defines
//structs
//typedefs, but don't hide *
//avoid globals, use with extern if really needed
//prototypes
#endif
```

Comment: Why not to use `#pragma once`?

Comment: @GlebWernher: [because it's not guaranteed to work in all C implementations](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.6)

Comment: @GlebWernher `#pragma once` is not part of the standard, and so may not be supported everywhere (although the major compilers do support it).